# Select all where [first letter starts with number or special characters]

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-like

I want to search in database the title start by a letter, number or special characters.

For letter is good I use this:

```
SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author LIKE 'B%';
```

But for number and special characters I need your help

```
SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author LIKE '[0-9]%';
```

Comment: I hope this video also helps https://youtu.be/tvRxVXBZKD0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator will not function like you want here, it takes static values and wildcards (`%` or `_`). You should use a regular expression with the mysql `REGEXP`. Something like:

```
SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author regexp '^[0-9B]'
```

Should find all authors that start with a `B` or a number. The `^` is a leading anchor meaning the string must start there. The `[]` builds a character class which is a list of characters, or a range when the `-` is used, `0-9` is any single number.

It is unclear what your "special characters" are but you might consider a negated character class, that is a list of not allowed characters. E.g.

```
SELECT author FROM lyrics WHERE author regexp '^[^.!?]'
```

would list all authors that didn't start with a `.`, `!`, or `?`.

Regex demos: https://regex101.com/r/qjjmNq/1/, https://regex101.com/r/qjjmNq/2/

Comment: How can we use regexp in a constraint expression?

Comment: @MohammadAfrashteh You can't use a regexp `check` with mysql constraints.

Answer (score 2):

Use `REGEXP` rather than `LIKE`

```
SELECT author 
FROM lyrics 
WHERE author REGEXP '[^[:alnum:]]'
```

Comment: for special characters i use `where not author regexp '^[0-9a-zA-Z]'`